How to display 3D objects in a specified location in AR.js
Using a webAR library called AR.js, I'm working on Github. I want to display the 3D object of the .gltf file in the coordinates I specified.
I don't think there's a problem with the .gltf file. I checked that the image in the gltf file is displayed in another job.
3D objects are not animation, they are normal 3D objects.
I want people to access my webAR camera through the URL, and see the 3D object
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>GeoAR.js demo</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-look-at-component@0.8.0/dist/aframe-look-at-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
  </head>
<body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden;">
    <a-scene 
        vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"
        renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true;"
        embedded 
        arjs="sourceType: webcam; videoTexture: true; debugUIEnabled: false;"
    >
        <a-assets>
            <a-asset-item 
                id="character1-model" 
                src="yamada.gltf"
            ></a-asset-item>
        </a-assets>
        <a-entity 
            gps-entity-place="latitude: 33; longitude: 130;"
            rotation="0 0 0"
            scale="1 1 1"
            gltf-model="#character1-model"
        ></a-entity>

        <a-camera 
            gps-camera 
            rotation-reader 
            look-controls-enabled='false' 
            arjs-look-controls='smoothingFactor: 0.1'
      ></a-camera>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>

But, only the webAR camera works and the 3D object doesn't show.
How should I solve it
